# Shortcut to Open Home Folder now opens tab instead

Tags: pantheon-files, files

I had set up Win+E to open Home folder long ago (Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Applications -> Home Folder).

A rather recent update has changed the behavior from opening a new window to opening a tab in the existing Files window. This is extremely annoying for me since I have 4 monitors and use multiple desktops. Now when I use the shortcut, it changes to the desktop where it was last active.

How can I change the behavior back to what it was before where it would open a new window on the active desktop?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Try reporting this issue to elementary OS developers on Files page: https://github.com/elementary/files

Comment: Huh, I suspected that it worked differently in the past but wasn't sure. Now I know they changed it, thanks :) btw I think it's the same for terminal too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right the behaviour changed - in response to issues raised by others.  What you can do is to disable your existing Application shortcut and create a Custom shortcut with the command `io.elementary.files -n ~`.  This will always open a new window containing one tab at the Home folder.  I am not sure what the behaviour regarding where on multiiple monitors it will appear will be - that is governed by the window manager (gala) not Files.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy, that fixes my issue perfectly. The monitor hop was simply a result of only a single window handling WIN+E - so the issue is resolved.